# Difference between 'RegExp' and regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm just getting into regular expressions with Javascript... And I seem to have gone on and confused myself...

Some googling here and there didn't do me any good either...

I know the Javascript syntax of:

```
var str = "Hello!";
var x = new RegExp(...);
document.write = x.eval(str);
```

Am I missing something here?

Edit: Apparently I wasn't clear... I am new to Javascript Regular Expressions. From my understanding, regex and regexp are different. If so, what is the difference?

Comment: How is the title related to the body of your question?

Comment: "Regexp" and "regex" are two common abbreviations of "regular expression." Is that the source of confusion?

Comment: @reve_etrange - Yes, it might be... I don't know though... If I did, I wouldn't have to ask...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are "RegExp class" syntax:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("/[a-z]+/","i");
```

and "RegExp literal" syntax:

```
var pattern = /[a-z]+/i;
```

Each of these have their own advatages. The class syntax can handle variables, this way you can create dynamic regular expressions, the literal systax on the other hand is shorter, and you dont have to escape so much.

After you have your pattern, you can use a few regex methods, for example:

```
text.match(pattern);
text.replace(pattern,replacement);

pattern.exec(text);
pattern.test(text);
```

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript's `RegExp` instances don't have an `eval` function, you might be thinking of [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) or [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Example:

```
var rex = /^\d+$/;
//Or  var rex = new RegExp("^\\d+$");
//Note how within quotes you have to escape backslashes

if (rex.test(someValue)) {
  display("Yup, it's all digits");
}
else {
  display("Nope, there are non-digits there or it's blank.");
}
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/odico5/2)

Comment: Depends, in Firefox they seem to have ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Eval (but of course it does not do what one might expect).

Comment: @Felix: It's not in the standard. So perhaps I should say *ECMAScript*'s `RegExp` doesn't have it ("JavaScript" still being a trademark of Oracle licensed to Mozilla).

Comment: Actually I was just kidding... :)

Comment: Glad we sorted that out :D ;)

Comment: This returns `true` for `abc123`, because of the `.`. Don't you mean `^\d+$`?

Comment: @pimvdb: Thanks, yes, talk about a stoopid place for a typo. Fixed.